# Extra space after new command using xparse

Tags: spacing, xparse, xspace

I was trying to write a macro that could take either one of two arguments and produce different outputs for both cases. For that, I used to package [xparse](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse). Here is the macro I wrote:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english, makeindex, final]{memoir}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xparse}             
\DeclareDocumentCommand\fig{om}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {(fig. \ref{#2})\xspace}
    {(fig. \ref{#2}.#1)\xspace}
}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

This it text I want to type \fig[A]{fig1}. And it is the same with the only one argument as well \fig{fig1}.

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{}
\caption[test figure]{Test figure. A big black box}
\label{fig1}
\end{center}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

The problem is that the new command generate automatically a space after the text and I can figure out how to remove it. I tried the [xspace](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace) package but it does not seem to work...

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have two spurious spaces:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\fig{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {(fig. \ref{#2})\xspace}
    {(fig. \ref{#2}.#1)\xspace}%
}
```

Of course the definition is cleaner with

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\fig{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {(fig. \ref{#2})}
    {(fig. \ref{#2}.#1)}%
  \xspace
}
```

There is no need to terminate the two lines where I haven't put `%` because TeX doesn't consider spaces when looking for arguments; they don't harm, anyway, so you may prefer

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand\fig{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
    {(fig. \ref{#2})}%
    {(fig. \ref{#2}.#1)}%
  \xspace
}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thanks a lot. One last question though: what exactly is the purpose of the % at the end of the lines?

Comment: @Wiliam An end of line counts as a space. With `%` we make TeX not see it.